# Get the resolution of a 2nd or 3rd monitor

Tags: windows-xp, autoit

How would I go about fetching the resolution of a 2nd or 3rd monitor via an AutoIT script?

Is there a specific function available for this?

Comment: Does moving the mouse outside the monitors boundaries and then reading and calculating it's actual position work? You can save your previous mouse position and set it again afterwards so nobody will see this happening ;-)

I got this working for some proper positioning problems in some strange GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered a [3rd party library](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/59919-multi-monitor-library/page__p__450986__hl__multi%20monitor__fromsearch__1#entry450986). It can return the resolutions of each monitor relative to the default display.

I just got an idea how to order them properly as well. I'll have to add a small section to the library where it assigns the smallest x value (includes negative integers) to be the first monitor, the next smallest the 2nd monitor, so on and so forth.

An example to enumerate all physical monitors and obtain their x resolution:

```
Dim $x = 0, $_enum, $_xRes, $_xResPre
Do
    $_enum = _WinAPI_EnumDisplayDevices("", $x)
    If $_enum[3] = 35 OR $_enum[3] = 33 Then
        $x+=1
        $_xResPre = _MonitorAndDesktopInfo()
        $_xRes = $_xResPre[$x][1]
        msgbox(0, "", $_xRes)
    Else
        $x+=1
    EndIf
Until NOT $_enum[3]
```